# Let me know about ANFIS premise prameters

Tags: artificial-intelligence, fuzzy-logic

I wanna ask about Adaptive Neuro Fuzzy Inference System (ANFIS) method. I used clustering to find fuzzy rules and used the mean and deviation standard of each cluster for initialization of the first premise parameters (c and a) of membership function. c is from the mean, and a is from the deviation standard

Now, my problem is I find that there's a cluster that have deviation standard = 0 (zero),  so it can't be premise parameter (where the deviation standard will be "a" parameter of membership function) because it will the gbell membership function undefined.

If a=0, how can I calculated the gbell membership function of ANFIS?
Is there any solution of finding rules and membership function of ANFIS that could be implemented in clustering?
Because I have to make ANFIS manual and I was banned to use MATLAB and I should make ANFIS in java programming and I have to do the manual first.

Thank you.

Comment: A cluster has zero standard deviation iff it is constant.

Comment: Your question is rather hard to understand. Can you try to clarify?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus. So, I mean that I will use the standard deviation for the parameter "a" of gbell membership function. But if a=0, gbell membership function can't be calculated.

Comment: I have revised it